# How is this googledrive.com phishing possible?

Tags: security, phishing

Recently I received a mail with the link: `http://googledrive.com/host/0B0uWu3qbasSeVjNCY1Nkekx5UkU`

When I opened it, it showed a phishing page to grab my user name and password but surprisingly the certificate the website provided is a legitimate google certificate. How can a phishing site provide a valid server authentication certificate from google?

Comment: I've put the link as code so it can't be clicked inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I understand it. It is a hosted web page on google drive. Please see the following link for more details: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

So the attackers hosted a page which looks exactly like google login page and the browsers could not find it because the certificate is a valid google drive certificate.